# Is it too late to negotiate my offer?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I move out of state last year left the company I was with and found a new job with a local company. They offered me a remote position but I declined. I am unhappy at my current company and my old employer offered me the remote position (and salary) again and I accepted. Now my current employer has offered me a substantial increase in pay if I stay. Is it too late to renegotiate with the other employer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you done the math on how long you are going to stay at either job?

Sounds like your current company is a position that does not have a lot of longevity to it. If you say you do not like it now, what's to say you will like it more with more money? You may be looking for another job before long, possibly after being let go for being more expensive than other resources. They may just intend to raise your salary and replace you quickly, at a time that is convenient for them and very inconvenient for you.

Even if you hadn't yet accepted the remote employer's offer and tried to negotiate it higher, they may have rejected your efforts. If you try to renegotiate it now, it is likely they will never want to work together again. This could be very dangerous if the previous paragraph holds true.

Culture is very important to many companies. If the remote company values their culture and their culture is not accepting of people focused on money, it's very likely they will not look kindly on your efforts.

Instead, I would stay with the remote offer, but pass along the offer from the local company to whomever you are negotiating with at the remote company. Let them know what you gave up to stay with their offer and don't bring it up again until it is time for a review. That may work in your favor to get the best of both worlds in the long run.

Comment: The place I am with now I do not intend to stay and accepting their offer isn't really an option in my mind. It just made me think that I possibly should have tried to ask for more money when my old company asked me back. If I were seeking employment or hadn't worked for them before I wouldn't even consider asking for more. I just know they are very excited to have me back and am wondering if I missed my opportunity to have a higher salary.

Comment: In that case, I think this is a really good outcome for your goals if you show your original company the offer you got. They will both learn that you care about this kind of thing and that your loyalty is to them at the same time. It will make a difference at your next review. Lastly, welcome to StackExchange and please be sure to "accept" the answer you are most satisfied with when you can! :)